# Migration to new server, left with default theme?

Tags: templating, migration

I have migrated a website that uses Craft CMS over to a new server. The instructions that I followed were outlines in this post: [Migration of Craft CMS from one host to another](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13982/migration-of-craft-cms-from-one-host-to-another/26694#26694)

The domain name in question is : glosenterprise.co.uk - this is how its meant to look. Here is a screenshot of how it is looking on the server.

[image: Glos Enterprise]

I am completely new to Craft CMS but to me it looks as though its not pulling in the theme that was created for the live site.

Is there anything obvious that I missing or a direction that people can point me in?

Comment: Did you move the files (especially the templates folder) to your new server?

Comment: Yes, I copied all files. However, I realised that there was an index.html in the public root and in the /new route on my server that were not on the old site. Must have been where I installed a fresh copy. I deleted these files and the site is displaying as it should.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the other comment. There were files from the fresh installation of Craft that I needed to delete. Once removed the template shown as intended.